# Fourier multiplier and applications

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $\mu$ be in $\mathcal D (\mathbb R^d)$ with $\mu \geq 0$, i.e. $\mu$ is a test function. Furthermore, we assume $\mu (\xi) =1$ when $|\xi|<1$ and $\mu (\xi) =0$ when $|\xi| \geq 2$. Why is the following true? For $j=1,2,3,...,d$ and $\lambda >0$, $\|\mu (\lambda D)\partial_{j}f\|_{L^2} \leq C \lambda^{-\frac{d+2}{2}}\|f\|_{L^1}$ for some constant $C$.

I think this is related to Fourier multiplier but after I checked relevant notes, I still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

We begin by using Parseval to compute
$$
\Vert \mu(\lambda D) \partial_j f \Vert_{L^2}^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \vert \mu(\lambda \xi) i \xi_j \hat{f}(\xi) \vert^2 d\xi.
$$
Then we estimate 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \vert \mu(\lambda \xi) i \xi_j \hat{f}(\xi) \vert^2 d\xi \le \Vert \hat{f} \Vert_{L^\infty}^2 \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |\mu(\lambda \xi)|^2 |\xi|^2 d\xi=  \Vert \hat{f} \Vert_{L^\infty}^2 \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |\mu(\omega)|^2 \left\vert \frac{\omega}{\lambda}\right\vert^2 \frac{d\omega}{\lambda^d} \\
= \lambda^{-d-2} \Vert \hat{f} \Vert_{L^\infty}^2  \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |\mu(\omega)|^2 |\omega|^2 d\omega = C_\mu \lambda^{-d-2} \Vert \hat{f} \Vert_{L^\infty}^2.
$$
Note here that $C_\mu$ is finite since $\mu$ is a test function, and it doesn't actually depend on $j$ due to the way we have estimated things.  On the other hand we know that 
$$
\Vert \hat{f} \Vert_{L^\infty} \le \Vert f \Vert_{L^1}.
$$
Combining all these then shows that 
$$
\Vert \mu(\lambda D) \partial_j f \Vert_{L^2}^2 \le C_\mu \lambda^{-d-2} \Vert \hat{f} \Vert_{L^1}^2,
$$
and so the estimate you want follows by taking the square root of both sides.

Comment: I don't get your 1st step. Did you mean $\int|\frac{\hat{\mu}(\xi / \lambda)}{|\lambda|} \ast i \xi \hat{f}|^2 d \xi$ ?

Comment: No.  For a function $\psi$ the action of the operator $\psi(D)$ is given via the Fourier transform by multiplication, i.e. $\mathcal{F}[\psi(D) f](\xi) = \psi(\xi) \mathcal{F}f(\xi)  $.

Comment: It is unclear that's what the OP meant

Comment: I disagree.  The phrase "Fourier multiplier" is used twice in the post, and this is the standard way of defining an operator via its "symbol."  Moreover, this leads precisely to the estimate that OP asked for.

Comment: what is $D$ to you ?